# SQL: LEFT JOIN based on effective date period of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables: [transaction_table] (t) and [rate_table] (r)

I want to FROM [transaction_table] LEFT JOIN [rate_table] according to the t.transaction_date and r.effective_date and the product.
Anyone know how?  Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:
but it returns undesired outcome

```
SELECT t.*, r.rate 
FROM [transaction_table] t 
LEFT JOIN [rate_table] r on (t.product = r.product and t.transaction_date >= r.effective_date)
```

Desired Outcome: Transaction Table LEFT JOIN Rate Table, with rate according to the effective_date

| transaction_date | product | amt | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 200 | 0.2 |
| 2020-04-01 | A | 200 | 0.3 |
| 2020-04-01 | B | 100 | 0.1 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 200 | 0.5 |

[Transaction_Table]: contains all transactions of different products

| transaction_date | product | amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 200 |
| 2020-04-01 | A | 200 |
| 2020-04-01 | B | 100 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 200 |

[Rate_Table]: contains rate adjustement of different products with an "effective_date"

| effective_date | product | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | A | 0.2 |
| 2019-01-01 | B | 0.1 |
| 2020-04-01 | A | 0.3 |
| 2020-09-01 | A | 0.5 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining all rates before the transaction date while you only want to get the newest of these. You can achieve this with a `TOP(1)` query in an `OUTER APPLY`

```
select t.*, r.rate 
from transaction_table t 
outer apply
(
  select top(1) *
  from rate_table r 
  where r.product = t.product 
  and r.effective_date <= t.transaction_date
  order by r.effective_date desc
);
```

or in a subquery in the `SELECT` clause:

```
select
  t.*,
  (
    select top(1) r.rate 
    from rate_table r 
    where r.product = t.product 
    and r.effective_date <= t.transaction_date
    order by r.effective_date desc
  ) as rate
from transaction_table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `APPLY` operator to get the latest `rate` by `product` and based on latest `effective_date`

```
SELECT t.*, r.rate 
FROM   [transaction_table] t 
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT TOP (1) r.rate
           FROM   [rate_table] r 
           WHERE  t.product          = r.product 
           AND    t.transaction_date >= r.effective_date
           ORDER BY r.effective_date DESC
       ) r
```

---

You may also want to use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY` if there are possibility of a non matching `rate` in the `rate_table`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a derived table in which you define an end date for the rate by getting the next effective date using [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), i.e.

```
SELECT  tt.transaction_date,
        tt.product,
        tt.amt,
        rt.rate
FROM    Transaction_Table AS tt
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  rt.effective_date, 
                    rt.product,
                    rt.rate,
                    end_date = LEAD(rt.effective_date) 
                                OVER(PARTITION BY rt.product ORDER BY rt.effective_date)
            FROM    rate_table AS rt
        ) AS rt
            ON rt.product = tt.product
            AND rt.effective_date <= tt.transaction_date
            AND (rt.end_date > tt.transaction_date OR rt.end_date IS NULL);
```

Or you can use [`OUTER APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) with `TOP 1` and then order by `effective_date` to get the latest rate prior to the transaction date:

```
SELECT  tt.transaction_date,
        tt.product,
        tt.amt,
        rt.rate
FROM    Transaction_Table AS tt
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP (1) rt.rate
            FROM    rate_table AS rt
            WHERE   rt.product = tt.product
            AND     rt.effective_date <= tt.transaction_date
            ORDER BY rt.effective_date DESC
        ) AS rt;
```

I would typically approach this using the first method as it is more likely that your rate table is significantly smaller than transaction table, but depending on your overall data and indexes you may find `OUTER APPLY` performs better.

If you are dealing with very high volumes of data and performance is an issue then materialising your rate table will probably help, e.g.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#rate', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #rate;
    
CREATE TABLE #rate
(
        Product CHAR(1) NOT NULL, --Change type as necessary
        FromDate DATE NOT NULL,
        ToDate DATE NULL,
        Rate DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL, -- Change type as necessary
    PRIMARY KEY (Product, FromDate)
);
INSERT #rate(Product, FromDate, ToDate, Rate)
SELECT  rt.product,
        rt.effective_date, 
        end_date = LEAD(rt.effective_date) 
                    OVER(PARTITION BY rt.product ORDER BY rt.effective_date),
        rt.rate
FROM    rate_table AS rt;


SELECT  tt.transaction_date,
        tt.product,
        tt.amt,
        rt.rate
FROM    Transaction_Table AS tt
        LEFT JOIN #rate AS rt
            ON rt.product = tt.product
            AND rt.FromDate <= tt.transaction_date
            AND (rt.ToDate > tt.transaction_date OR rt.ToDate IS NULL);
```